# C++ variable change value "on its own" in a program including multi-thread

Tags: c++

I am very confused, because a variable (fuel) is turning into 0 "on its own", which I'm sure isn't true because computer are not magical creatures. However, I checked all the time the variable is used, and nothing strange appear. However, when it is, it's from one thread to another. Here is some piece of the code :

In the main

```
dataCollectorFTL dataCollector1;
...
expertModule expertModule1(dataCollector1, gazeCoordinate1, communicationModule1);
```

In expertModule .h :

```
public:

dataCollectorFTL& theDataCollector;
communicationModule& theCommunicationModule;
```

...

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point lastRefresh;
bool isFighting;
int previousEnemyHull;
long fuel;
```

...

```
expertModule::expertModule(dataCollectorFTL &aDataCollectorFTL, gazeCoordinate &aGazeCoordinate, communicationModule &aCommunicationModule);
```

Then, in the expertModule.cpp :

```
expertModule::expertModule(dataCollectorFTL &aDataCollectorFTL, gazeCoordinate &aGazeCoordinate, communicationModule &aCommunicationModule) : theDataCollector(aDataCollectorFTL) , theGazeCoordinate(aGazeCoordinate) , theCommunicationModule(aCommunicationModule) {

    isFighting = false;
    lastRefresh = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    fuel = theDataCollector.dataFuel;

}
```

...

```
if (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()-lastRefresh).count()>500){

    if (isFighting && ( expertModule::fuel =! theDataCollector.dataFuel || theDataCollector.dataEnemyHull == 0)){
        isFighting = false;
        previousEnemyHull = theDataCollector.dataEnemyHull;
    } else if (!isFighting && theDataCollector.dataEnemyHull != previousEnemyHull ) {
        isFighting = true;      
        expertModule::fuel = theDataCollector.dataFuel;
    }


    std::cout<<expertModule::fuel<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<theDataCollector.dataFuel<<std::endl;        
    lastRefresh = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
}
```

With this code, the expertModule variable "fuel" worth the exact value at the time of initialization, and then goes to 0 while theDataCollector.dataFuel doesn't change.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: This sound like a job for a debugger (and perhaps valgrind)

Comment: One common source of confusion is that you somewhere (like in the constructor) create a copy of your data, and all updates go to the copy. Then surprisingly the original is unchanged. Just a guess.

Comment: For anyone who may look at this one day : the problem is in the "if" condition. I wrote =! instead of !=, so fuel took the value (=) of the bool opposite (!) of the next value, which wasn't 0, so fuel became 0.

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you advice how to debug this. One option that also improves your design is to make the variable private and introduce a setter `setFuel`. On every call of the setter you can print the variable or include an assert. I guess you can find the error quite fast this way.